# Node js, require everywhere or add a property to req

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-modules

The question is about architecture.
I got a module 'db', which establishes connection to mongodb and has a class with schemas, models etc. I export exemplar of that class.
Should i just require('db') in every route file or just do this in one:

```
server.on('request', function(req) {
  req.db = db;
});
```

db.js:

```
"use strict";
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
var conn = mongoose.connection;
conn.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
conn.once('open', function() {
  console.log("Connected to MongoDB.");
});

class db {
  constructor() {
    //Users
    this._usersSchema = mongoose.Schema(
      {
        username: String,
        password: String,
        email: String
      });
    this.Users = mongoose.model("Users", this._usersSchema);
  }
}

module.exports = new db();
```

Comment: Depends on your db module. If you module reuses the same instance every time you require it, you just have to instantiate it. If not you can pass it along. You have to give more information though.

Comment: I added some info about module

Comment: With mongoose you don't have to pass along the db connection. Just use your schema models to interact with the database. The module takes care of the rest.

Comment: The plan was to pass the object with all models, so i can use them everywhere. Can you answer more specific please? require everywhere, req.db = db, or maybe something else?

Comment: Have you considered putting it in globals?  Not saying that's clearly the best option, but it is a reasonable one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you will find differing opinions, but I prefer to `require` wherever I need it. `modules` in node are singletons, so you are always getting the same instance. And I like to separate out my controller logic into their own files away from the routes. Moreover the logic does not expect the complete request and response objects. The reason is I can then use the same code to grab data necessary to serve an API endpoint or render the view server-side without having the mock an entire request and response object.